# Android: custom ViewPager Animation

Tags: android, bitmap, android-viewpager

Inside the Google+ Photos app, one can swipe from one image to the next in a viewpager (in single image show mode). On swiping, there is the known card  stack-effect.
How can I implement exactely this effect into my ViewPager?

Comment: Do you mean that effect? http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#depth-page

Comment: Take a look at [JazzyViewPager](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a viewpager pagetransformer to create different transitions between pages. See the developer training page

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer

Example Code:
Zoom Out Page Transformer

```
public class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
private static final float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
    int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

    if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.setAlpha(0);

    } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
        // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
        float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
        float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
        float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
        if (position < 0) {
            view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
        } else {
            view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
        }

        // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
        view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
        view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);

        // Fade the page relative to its size.
        view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA +
                (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) /
                (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

    } else { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }
}
```

}